# Need Regex to find "xxxx",,,,, of "yyyy",,,, and remove

Tags: mysql, regex, csv, text

I have been given a very large CSV file of data I need to import to a MySQL db. Unfortunately, the CSV file has a text footer after every 50 lines of data which looks like this:

```
0,,,,,," of 2,401",,,,
10,,,,,," of 2,401",,,,
999,,,,,," of 2,401",,,,
"1,000",,,,,," of 2,401",,,,
"2,396",,,,,," of 2,401",,,,

...etc
```

As you can see, the pattern changes when the numbers get to 1,000 (They start using double quotes to surround the beginning Page #).This is beyond my understanding of RegEx. I need a Regular Expression to identify all of these lines and remove them.

Comment: you could probably get away with:  /[^,]+,,,,,," of 2,401",,,,$//    that's pretty lazy but I suspect it's enough for a one time fixer

Comment: `^("?)[\d,]+?\1,+"\s*of [\d,]+",+$` or `^(?:[\d,]+|"[\d,]+"),+"\s*of [\d,]+",+$`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    (\d+|"(\d+,\d+)+"),+" of (\d+|(\d+,\d+)+)",+(\n|$)
```

It would match on all cases below:

0,,,,,," of 2,401",,,,

10,,,,,," of 2,401",,,,

999,,,,,," of 2,401",,,,

"1,000",,,,,," of 2,401",,,,

"2,396",,,,,," of 2,401",,,,

10,,,,,," of 2,401,000",,,,

"1,999,822",,,,,," of 2,401,000",,,,